# After adding Babel every Vite app crashes. can you explain why and how to avoid this issue?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, vite

I have two projects (one is for testing current issue) which are simple vite/react no typescript apps.

when i run

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
```

apps start crashing with

```
failed to load config from C:\userpath\project\vite.config.jserror during build:
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: File
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\userpath\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
```

ok, then i tried

```
rm -r node_modules
del package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm i
```

and we got new issue here

```
npm run dev 

12:02:37 [vite] Internal server error: Cannot redefine property: File
  Plugin: vite:react-babel
  File: C:/userpath/st4/src/main.jsx
      at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\userpath\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
```

switching node 17.5.0 | 18.17.1 | 20.5 -7 do not fix this. so problem is - when i'm adding babel, this behaviour seems to occur. if anyone had the same, please share any thoughts and fixes. very grateful!!!

Comment: Why did you add Babel? Vite should already be taking care of any transpiling tasks

Comment: came to a project with Babel (edit my Q with package.json). I played with babel on my side project and got same behaviour. this is the only explanation i can give.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why did you add it to this project? Also, why have you added `vite-plugin-vue` to this React project?

Comment: cant answer this right now, just new commer to project. added it to MY project just to test if it's babel. other dev who worked on this have no problems with running app and either cand explain how is that. hope i'm clear here.

Answer (score 1):

you can just remove `plugin:[react()]` in vite.config.ts to fix it